# Programming Techniques to reduce text file size

Tags: python, optimization, file-io

I am writing a multidimensional array data to a text file. I am doing this row wise. The size of the file keeps growing. what techniques should I follow to get the least possible size for the output file?

Comment: How sparse is the data? If the data is pretty sparse, you could just store the positions of elements of non-zero value.

Comment: Does the file need to remain human-readable?

Comment: The data is quite sparse (approx 32k dimensions with probably around 200 values present). I am using -1 as a place holder for missing values(or 0). I need it in this form as I am further processing the data.

Comment: Is it required to be a CSV file?

Comment: I want it in either csv or tsv form (just to separate the dimensions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your array has many zeros you can use sparse matrix representation: instead of writing the whole matrix to the file, only write the nonzero elements (of course, you need to write each element with its indices, one by one). Suppose you want to write this matrix:

```
0 0 0 2
1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 3 0
0 0 0 0
```

You can write this to the file:

```
0 3 2
1 0 1
3 2 3
```

In each line, the first number is the row, the second is the column and the third is the stored value.

If you are writing the file as text, you can switch to binary format: when you write text, you will use a byte for each digit; in binary, you use fixed amount of bytes per number, and wouldn't have to represent spaces and newlines:

Writing the numbers `100 200 300` to a file takes 11 bytes if you use text format. But they may be written using 6 bytes if you write three 16-bit integers. In Python, use "wb" and "rb" modes for opening binary files, then write them as bytes:

```
f = open('file', 'wb')
f.write('%c' % 123)
f.close()
```

Or -- more efficiently,

```
import array
f = open('file', 'wb')
data = array.array('B')
data.append(1)
data.append(2)
data.append(3)
data.tofile(f)
f.close()
```

Otherwise, then you should probably try compressing the data structure, using standard techniques. Since you tagged your question with `python`, you will probably be interested in these [Python libraries for data compression](http://docs.python.org/library/archiving.html)

There is also this nice [introduction to data compression](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~guyb/realworld/compression.pdf), a bit heavy on the theoretical side, in case you would like to know more about it.

Comment: How do I switch to binary format when writing text to a file(in python). My output is going to be ints 0-100

Comment: Just out of curiosity because of your "more efficiently" comment - I assumed python's write would buffer the output when not writing to the console, not true?

Comment: @Voo: using data.tofile(f) writes the whole array at once to the file, and can be optimized more easily (the full size of the array is known to the function). But I didn't run any benchmarks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Because the data is quite sparse, you can use [SciPyPackages / Sparse](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) About I/O can look [this](http://www.scipy.org/SciPyPackages/Sparse#head-c3d2c28b185d1ddb210a2da2e484be7480ba5800)

A sparse matrix is simply a matrix with a large number of zero values.

So， If you want write code by youself. When save `sparse matrix`, you only need output the position of no-zero element and the element value. For example:

the `sparse matrix` :

```
1 0 0 1
0 0 0 0
0 0 5 0
0 0 0 10
```

the data need save to file is:

```
0 0 1
0 3 1
2 2 5
3 3 10
```

When the `sparse matrix` grower, this method can reduce the data to save into the `file`.

And when to use `data file`, you only need recover the `original matrix` from the data.

Good luck